# How to plot lines where the segments/points are delivered via a JSON request in PaperJS/JS?

Tags: javascript, json, paperjs

What's the optimal way to plot paths/segments using PaperJS or general in JS, where the data I receive for this is via JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way of parsing your JSON data depends on its shape but more generally, displaying dots in `Paper.js` consists of drawing a serie of circles.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating a possible implementation.

```
// This represents the data that you receive, assuming that each point is a [x,y] coordinates array.
const points = [[62, 44], [182, 108], [246, 220], [231, 35], [357, 419], [246, 292], [7, 204], [188, 375], [70, 406], [481, 274], [341, 314], [158, 269], [446, 204], [78, 197], [287, 207], [435, 317], [11, 168], [467, 110], [195, 282], [481, 14], [20, 384], [19, 262], [133, 205], [105, 261], [16, 457], [83, 401], [104, 62], [25, 188], [6, 307], [13, 118], [157, 258], [35, 155], [38, 93], [332, 347], [216, 351], [42, 92], [96, 168], [201, 446], [353, 336], [444, 348], [19, 452], [433, 173], [112, 227], [419, 153], [378, 47], [38, 89], [150, 122], [423, 58], [61, 446], [14, 331]];

for (let [x, y] of points) {
    new Path.Circle({
        center: [x, y],
        radius: 2,
        fillColor: 'orange'
    });
}
```

The only downside of this approach is that if you have a lot of points, performance can be an issue.
If this is the case and if you don't need to interact with the dots later, you can simply fallback on drawing the circles on the canvas directly using canvas context [arc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) method.

```js
// This represents the data that you receive, assuming that each point is a [x,y] coordinates array.
const points = [[62, 44], [182, 108], [246, 220], [231, 35], [357, 419], [246, 292], [7, 204], [188, 375], [70, 406], [481, 274], [341, 314], [158, 269], [446, 204], [78, 197], [287, 207], [435, 317], [11, 168], [467, 110], [195, 282], [481, 14], [20, 384], [19, 262], [133, 205], [105, 261], [16, 457], [83, 401], [104, 62], [25, 188], [6, 307], [13, 118], [157, 258], [35, 155], [38, 93], [332, 347], [216, 351], [42, 92], [96, 168], [201, 446], [353, 336], [444, 348], [19, 452], [433, 173], [112, 227], [419, 153], [378, 47], [38, 89], [150, 122], [423, 58], [61, 446], [14, 331]];

const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

for (let [x, y] of points) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```